# Javascript accessing a child array using it in PDFKit - NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am using pdfKit in a nodeJS project - to generate PDF's.

I have an array where data is stored and used to populate a table, which is working.

However I cannot seam to figure out how to retrieve data out of a object within the array. In the below example I want to retrieve the `child` object.

I need some sort of loop but cannot figure out how to add it!

How do I create a table including the Child data, as below?

```
var dataArray = {
id: 12332,
products: [{
      price: '10',
      amount: '20',
      child: [{ color: 'red', id: 101},{ color: 'green', id: 103}]
    }, {
      price: '55',
      amount: '23',
      child: [{ color: 'black', id: 106}]
    }]
```

}

I'm trying to get my table to look like:

```
    | price | amount |
    ------------------
    | 10.   | 20.    |
    ------------------
    ||  red   101   ||
      --------------
    ||  green  103  ||
    ------------------
    | 10.   | 20.    |
    ------------------
    ||  black   106 ||
      --------------
```

This is my JS code so far:

```
let i,
   invoiceTableTop = 330;

generateTableRow(
   doc,
   invoiceTableTop,
   "price",
   "amount",
);
generateHr(doc, invoiceTableTop + 20);


for (i = 0; i < dataArray.products.length; i++) {
   const item = dataArray.products[i];
   const position = invoiceTableTop + (i + 1) * 30;

   generateTableRow(
      doc,
      position,
      item.price,
      item.amount
   );

}

function generateHr(doc, y) {
   doc
      .strokeColor("#aaaaaa")
      .lineWidth(1)
      .moveTo(50, y)
      .lineTo(550, y)
      .stroke();
}

function generateTableRow(doc, y, c1, c2) {
   doc
      .fontSize(10)
      .text(c1, 50, y)
      .text(c2, 150, y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner loop to go through the colors array.

Once you have your `item` object, loop through it:

```
for (i = 0; i < item.child.length; i++) {
    let child = item.child[i];
    let color = child.color;
    let id = child.id;
    // do whatever with these values
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a few things to fit this code into my project. However I cannot figure it out. I can only seem to loop it in one of the objects.

Comment: @tbowden It has to go inside your existing loop, such as under `const item = dataArray.products[i];`